Tags "price" and "exchange-rate" appear to be synonymous
The tags price and exchange-rate appear to be synonymous. We should merge them. Which one should we keep as the master of the synonym pair? 

As noted in chat, I think exchange-rate is a slightly more descriptive term. Price could be talking about the price of an item in BTC.

I've merged price into exchange-rate.
